# FPDF and HTML2PDF script timeout issue

Tags: php, fpdf, html2pdf

I have a page that I get into a file_get_contents and if I add a echo on my string, I get the right view i want.

Now im adding the FPDF tool with the HTML2PDF Script and im getting some:

> Uncaught ERROR 1 tag HEADER does not yet exist

I have then added this to my html2pdf.class.php file (bc the same error come with the SECTION tag after adding HEADER)

```
/**
     * tag : HEADER
     * mode : OPEN
     *
     * @param  array $param
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _tag_open_HEADER($param)
    {
        return $this->_tag_open_B($param, 'header');
    }

    /**
     * tag : SECTION
     * mode : OPEN
     *
     * @param  array $param
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _tag_open_SECTION($param)
    {
        return $this->_tag_open_B($param, 'section');
    }

    /**
     * tag : HEADER
     * mode : CLOSE
     *
     * @param  array $param
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _tag_close_HEADER($param)
    {
        return $this->_tag_close_B($param);
    }

    /**
     * tag : SECTION
     * mode : CLOSE
     *
     * @param  array $param
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _tag_close_SECTION($param)
    {
        return $this->_tag_close_B($param);
    }
```

After adding first the HEADER open/close tag i then got the error about the SECTION tag then i added that on the same way as the HEADER tag with the open/close tag, now i get this error..

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /var/www/domain.dk/public_html/_class/parsingCss.class.php on line 1246

Do someone know where i can increase the time ?

Comment: on localhost you can on php.ini on server side you need to ask your hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` Change 300 to whatever you want.

Comment: Im new in PHP.. do I just add that to the top of my main document or the html2pdf.class.php file ?

Comment: I'd add it to your class file for simplicity. Otherwise you'd need it in every file you called it from.